# How to change a Slider's Value with the mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, slider, mousewheel

I want to change the value of a [`Slider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider(v=vs.110).aspx) to the mouse wheel: When I scroll up, the `Slider's` `Value` property should increase and when I scroll down, it should decrease.
The behavior should be independent of the mouse position or the current focus.

Preferably the solution uses binding and is XAML only but a code-behind solution would suffice as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an attached behaviour that hooks up the `PreviewMouseWheel` event of the parent `Window` and sets the value of the `Slider`.

Using an attached behaviour enables you to encapsulate the functionality and reuse it for any `Slider` control without having to modify the code-behind file of each view.

Here is an example for your reference.

```
public class MouseWheelBehavior
{
    public static double GetValue(Slider slider)
    {
        return (double)slider.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetValue(Slider slider, double value)
    {
        slider.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Value",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(MouseWheelBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnValueChanged));

    public static Slider GetSlider(UIElement parentElement)
    {
        return (Slider)parentElement.GetValue(SliderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSlider(UIElement parentElement, Slider value)
    {
        parentElement.SetValue(SliderProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Slider",
        typeof(Slider),
        typeof(MouseWheelBehavior));


    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider slider = d as Slider;
        slider.Loaded += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(slider);
            if (window != null)
            {
                SetSlider(window, slider);
                window.PreviewMouseWheel += Window_PreviewMouseWheel;
            }
        };
        slider.Unloaded += (ss, ee) => 
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(slider);
            if(window != null)
            {
                SetSlider(window, null);
                window.PreviewMouseWheel -= Window_PreviewMouseWheel;
            }
        };
    }

    private static void Window_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = sender as Window;
        Slider slider = GetSlider(window);
        double value = GetValue(slider);
        if(slider != null && value != 0)
        {
            slider.Value += slider.SmallChange * e.Delta / value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Slider local:MouseWheelBehavior.Value="120" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a way of doing it with bindings or XAML but this fairly simple code-behind solution works:

```
MyPanel.PreviewMouseWheel += (sender, e)
    => MySlider.Value += MySlider.SmallChange * e.Delta / 120;
```

Some things of note:

- `MyPanel` can be any `Control`. The event will fire when the mouse is above this `Control` while using the wheel.
- You can use either the `MouseWheel` or the `PreviewMouseWheel` event. The latter one is more convenient if there are other controls handling the `MouseWheel` event (like a `ScrollViewer`).
- `Delta` will hold the value `120` when you move the mouse wheel up one tick. So you have to divide by this value to get the expected behavior.
- If `MySlider.Value` is bound to a property in your code, you should adjust the property's value instead of changing the `Slider` directly.

Comment: You could use an attached behaviour that hooks up the PreviewMouseWheel event of the parent window and sets the value of the Slider: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF. Using an attached behaviour enables you to encapsulate the functionality and reuse it for any Slider control without having to modify the code-behind file of each view. Let me know if you need a full sample.

Answer (score 0):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296501/8705305) *does* work, it has some severe drawbacks that made it unusable in my case:

- Only works for a single `Slider` control (whichever was created last)
- Works regardless of where the mouse is actually located (as long as it is over the window)
- Value changes are imprecise

An alternative that doesn't have these problems is possible using the official [`Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) nuget package:

### C#

```cs
public class MouseWheelSliderBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
{
    public double Amount
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(AmountProperty);
        set => SetValue(AmountProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AmountProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            nameof(Amount), 
            typeof(double), 
            typeof(MouseWheelSliderBehavior), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));

    private void AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Amount == 0.0) return;
        Slider slider = (Slider)sender;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            slider.Value += Amount;
        }
        else
        {
            slider.Value -= Amount;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel += this.AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseWheel -= this.AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseWheel;
    }
}
```

### XAML

Add the following namespace:

```xml
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

Then, to use the behavior:

```xml
<Slider>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:MouseWheelSliderBehavior Amount="1" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```

Whatever you set `Amount` to is *exactly* the amount that the slider value will change by.