# How to implement changing slider value with mouse wheel in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, slider, maui, mousewheel

Actually the question is in the title.
The [WPF solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294278/how-to-change-a-sliders-value-with-the-mouse-wheel) doesn't fit (or I haven't figured out how to adapt it), and I couldn't find anything else specific.

The solution from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16130) also could not be adapted, because Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiSlider is not converted to Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentPanel.

Comment: Not a big expert of WinUI, but maybe you could get the ContentPanel cast from another view in the page (an ancestor?) and raise an event when the mouse wheel value changes.

Comment: @Riccardo Minato. So it would be needed to purposely wrap the Slider in another element that can be converted to a ContentPanel? I wouldn't want to do that just to implement mouse wheel support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the windows, you can add the `PointerWheelChanged` event for the slider. Put the following code in the App's constructor:

```
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SliderHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Slider), (handler, view) =>
            {
#if WINDOWS
                var winslider = view.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Slider;
                winslider.PointerWheelChanged += (s,e) =>
                {
                    if (e.GetCurrentPoint(winslider).Properties.MouseWheelDelta>0)
                    {
                        view.Value++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view.Value--;
                    }
                };
#endif
            });
        }
```

The slider in the xaml is: `<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>`.

But I can't find a solution for the mac.

**Update:**

If you only want to do this for a special Slider. You can remove the code above from the App's constructor. And use it:

In the xaml :

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" x:Name="slider"/>
```

In the Page's OnHandlerChanged method:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
        var winslider = slider.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Slider;
        winslider.PointerWheelChanged += (s,e) =>
        {
            if (e.GetCurrentPoint(winslider).Properties.MouseWheelDelta>0)
            {
                slider.Value++;
            }
            else
            {
                slider.Value--;
            }
        };
#endif
    }
```

This will only work for the `x:Name="slider"`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really works. But, do I understand correctly that this is a common method for all elements of the Slider class? If so, what if there are several such elements and their behavior should be different?

Comment: Sorry for I can't understand what do you mean clearly. Did you mean you want all the sliders can use the wheel? If so, you can use `<Slider x:Name="slider"/>` and add the event for the `slider.Handler.PlatformView`. @Corhal

Comment: As I understand the specified Action in the AppendToMapping method will be called for each element of the Slider class. If there are two of them, then the action will be called twice. That's why the question arose: for which specific element it was called, in order to correctly define the method for its behavior. What you suggest in the comment (if I understand correctly), via the element name, will cause the event handler to be registered (added) repeatedly.

Comment: I checked and found a way through "view.Equals(slider1)" as an example. Where slider1 is the name of the element <Slider x:Name="slider1"/>.

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer. @Corhal

Comment: Or probably even easier (less expensive) "handler == slider1.Handler".

Comment: But you can't access the slider in the app.cs. @Corhal

Comment: The augmented solution is not exactly what is ideally needed. Example, let's say there are two Slider elements, but they should change the value differently per unit of mouse wheel movement. For example, the first one with a step of 2 and the second one with a step of 4. So we need to understand which element has an event.
But I have already sorted out this issue, so thanks again.

Comment: > "But you can't access the slider in the app.cs." But I don't need it. I can use the "view" parameter like in your example, but I needed to determine which element (slider1 or slider2) it corresponds to.

Comment: The update part is an example for slider1 but you can also use the code for slider2 and change the `value++` to `value = value +2`. @Corhal

Comment: Check out my answer below, it's a simplified version of what I needed. Added it so as not to further inflate the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from the respected Liyun Zhang, I formed a solution for several Slider elements:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.SliderHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(nameof(Slider), (handler, view) =>
    {
#if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Slider? winSlider = view.Handler?.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Slider;

        if (winSlider != null)
        {
            winSlider.PointerWheelChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                int step = 1;

                switch(handler)
                {
                    case slider1.Handler:
                        step = 2; //here you can replace a fixed value with a field or property
                        break;
                    case slider2.Handler;
                        step = 4; //here you can replace a fixed value with a field or property
                        break;
                }

                view.Value += e.GetCurrentPoint(winSlider).Properties.MouseWheelDelta / 120 * step;
            };
        }
#endif
    });
}
```

Where slider1 and slider1 elements are declared in the XAML layout as (example):

```
<Slider x:Name="slider1"/>
<Slider x:Name="slider2"/>
```